# C++ vector reference conversion

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, type-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

The following code refuses to compile.

The compiler is complaining of conversion from the vector reference to an int pointer, but I don't understand why. Is there some kind of a solution to this problem?

```
bool inSortedVectorHelper(int* front, int* back, int num)
{
  if(front==back || front > back )
    return false;

  int* mid = front+(back-front)/2;
  if((*mid) == num)
    return true;

  else if(num < (*mid))
    return inSortedVectorHelper(front,mid-1,num);
else
    return inSortedVectorHelper(mid+1,back,num);
}


bool inSortedVector(const std::vector<int> &sorted, int num)
{
  int* front,back;
  front = sorted.front();//both return references
  back = sorted.back();

  return inSortedVectorHelper(front, back, num);
}
```

Exact compiler output:

```
P5.cpp: In function ‘bool inSortedVector(const std::vector<int>&, int)’:
P5.cpp:62:9: error: invalid conversion from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int> >::value_type {aka int}’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
front = sorted.front();//both return references
      ^
P5.cpp:65:47: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
return inSortedVectorHelper(front, back, num);
                                           ^
P5.cpp: In function ‘bool inSortedVector(const std::vector<int>&, int)’:
P5.cpp:62:9: error: invalid conversion from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int> >::value_type {aka int}’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
front = sorted.front();//both return references
      ^
P5.cpp:65:47: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
return inSortedVectorHelper(front, back, num);
```

I can't believe I'm having this much trouble with a simple binary search function, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `int* front,back;` front is of a pointer type, back is not, and for your case, neither has to be of a pointer type. or you probably meant to use `begin()` and `end` together with iterators?

Comment: _"//both return references"_ Okay so why are you assigning the result to pointers? Also, I bet `int* front,back` is not doing what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

This should work without ugly code using pointers:

```
bool inSortedVector(const std::vector<int> &sorted, int num)
{
    return std::binary_search( sorted.begin(), sorted.end(), num );
}
```

if you want to re-implement `std::binary_search` you should learn how it is properly implemented over containers using iterators.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to use algorithm library

Comment: @Tyler at least you can use it as proper model for implementing your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
int *front, *back;
front = &sorted.front();
back = &(sorted.back()) + 1;
```

Comment: Looks good, but a brief explanation would help others understand the underlying logic, and thus avoid this type of mistake in the future. :)

Answer (score -1):

`front` and `back` return references to int (as your comments document). Your variables are pointers. You should rather write:

```
int *front, *back;
front = &(sorted.front()); //both return references
back = &(sorted.back());
```

Furthermore `&(sorted.front())` is equivalent to `sorted.data()` for non-bool vectors.

Comment: Except this will make `back` point to the last item, rather than one past it.

Comment: only `front` is a pointer in `int* front,back;`.  `back` is just an int.  this is evident in the fact that there were no errors for `back`